# Неустранимая ошибка E1027

Tags: c, visual-studio

Попробовал перейти в Visual Studio с дефолтного компилятора на `clang-cl`, поменяв параметр в свойствах проекта, обнаружил ошибку "`E1027`: *ошибка в командной строке: указаны несовместимые языковые режимы*", однако программа спокойно компилируется. При попытке вручную вписать параметры, отвечающие за стандарт языка, `-std=c17` и `-std=c++20` ошибка исчезает, но программа компилироваться по понятным причинам не хочет.

Upd: Ошибка просто висит в списке ошибок с вышеуказанным описанием. При этом помимо компиляции возможна и успешная отладка, так что эта ошибка в целом только монолит глаза.

P.S. На всякий случай прилагаю код тестовой программы.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    if (argc == 1)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        printf("%s%c", argv[i], i + 1 == argc ? '\n' : ' ');
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Вывод ошибки приложите

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1049?view=msvc-170

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло.